# Can CoreBluetooth report remaining battery life for peripherals?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I looked through `CoreBluetooth` documentation but I did not find any hints on this. Did I missed something or it really can't report such information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual GATT service you're referring to is known as the [Battery Service](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServiceViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.service.battery_service.xml). As the other answerer has commented, you must properly implement this service on the firmware side in order to read from it. However, using it you can subscribe and read from the [Battery Level Characteristic](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml) and get a value back in the range of 0 - 100%.

NOTE: If you're connecting two different iOS devices, you can just implement your own custom service to send the battery life.

Answer (score 2):

Your device needs to support those readings in order to obtain this data. There's no standard for reading battery life. If your device supports it, there should be specs on how to read it.